# R.string.** + string をするとR.string.**の部分に数字が出て来る問題

Tags: java, android

Android(Java)でアプリの更新を促すDialogを作成するために以下のコードを実装しております。

versionCodeはPackageInfoから取得したバージョン
latest_versionはJsonから取得した最新バージョン

```java
AlertDialog.Builder UpdateDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
UpdateDialog.setTitle("UPDATE!");
UpdateDialog.setMessage(R.string.update + "\nYOUR VERSION : " + versionCode + "\nLATEST VERSION : " + latest_version);
UpdateDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
UpdateDialog.setCancelable(false);
UpdateDialog.setPositiveButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        setState(PREFERENCE_BOOTED);
    }
});
UpdateDialog.create();
UpdateDialog.show();
```

するとDialogには

```
UPDATE

2131230759
YOUR_VERSION : 1
LATEST_VERSION : 3.1
```

と出てきてしまいます。
おそらく、R.stringを表示する際にうまくいってないようです。

もし解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

すいません。自己解決しました。

`getResources().getString(R.string.update)` するとintではなく、stringが取得できるようです。

**修正後のコード**

```
AlertDialog.Builder UpdateDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
//set title
UpdateDialog.setTitle("UPDATE!");
String update = getResources().getString(R.string.update);
UpdateDialog.setMessage(update + "\nYOUR VERSION : " + versionName + "\nLATEST VERSION : " + latest_version);//set content
UpdateDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);//set icon
UpdateDialog.setCancelable(false);
UpdateDialog.setPositiveButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        download();
    }
});
UpdateDialog.create();
UpdateDialog.show();
```

Comment: `MainActivity.this`が出てきているので、`getResources().`はなくても大丈夫な気がします（Activityに`getString()`があるため）